# Get Color Sidebar Icons Back in Mac OS finder Window

Tags: finder, macos, color

Suppose I want to come back to Color sidebar icon for Finder. For Lion I followed these instructions, but seems not working anymore (SIMBL is not working with Sierra):

http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/25/get-color-sidebar-icons-back-in-mac-os-x-10-7-lion-finder-windows/

So, do you know if there is a way to change from this fantastic soviet union gray sidebar to one with color?

thanks,
Andrea

Comment: You would need to modify system resources, which requires disabling SIP at the very least.

Comment: I installed mySIMBL, and it disabled my open/save file panel resources, so I had to remove it from Sierra Launch Agents, etc. Any other option? I miss the color sidebar...

Answer (score 3):

Use [mySIMBL](https://github.com/w0lfschild/mySIMBL)* instead, SIMBL has been non-functional since apple implemented System Integrity Protection. Once you've set up mySIMBL install the package at:

Sources >>> Wolf's tweaks >>> colorfulSidebar9.

Then restart Finder and you should have colored sidebar icons again.

* I am the developer of mySIMBL and colorfulSidebar9

Comment: Good solution! However you should disclose your affiliation with the package in your answer — just on principle, but it's also a [rule](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). (even though it's open source and free) :)

Comment: How is colorfulSidebar9 different from ColorfulSidebar from the following website? http://cooviewerzoom.web.fc2.com/colorfulsidebar.html

Comment: colorfulSidebar9 works on 10.9+

Comment: The link in your github description to the colorfulSidebar9.bundle is dead.

Comment: Note: mySIMBL has been replaced by MacForge, and both now require turning off SIP in recent versions of MacOS.